# How should I handle JWT token refresh in my Redux app?

Tags: javascript, redux, token, jwt

Our Redux application use JWT tokens for authentication. The access_token expires every 15 minutes and the refresh_token expires every 30 days. Both of them are provided by our API every time you log in and stored in the browser's local storage. If a secure endpoint receives a request with an expired token, it returns a 401 HTTP error.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed to handle the refresh process without having a negative impact on the user. From a technical point of view, here is what I would like to achieve:

- Action creator calls the API with an expired token
- Client receives a 401 HTTP error
- Client triggers a function that calls the API to obtain a new token (by providing the refresh token).
- If the call fails (refresh_token is expired), prompt the user the re-enter its credentials to re-obtain both tokens then re-attempt the original request.
- If the call succeeds, re-attempt the original request.

I would like to have a function that would handle the refreshing process and that would be called in the error handling portion of the action creator.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    export function handleError(dispatch, current_func, error, handling) {
        if(error.response) {
            if(error.response.status === 401 && readToken("token") !== null) {
                return attemptTokenRefresh(dispatch, current_func)
            }

            if(error.response.status === 422 && readToken("token") === null) {
                return attemptTokenRefresh(dispatch, current_func)
            }
        }

        return(handling())
    }

    export function attemptTokenRefresh(dispatch, on_success) {
        let token = readToken("refresh_token");

        let instance = axios.create({
            headers: {"Authorization": token}
        });

        instance.post("api/refresh").then(response => {
            if (response.data["token"]) {
                storeToken("token", response.data["token"]);
                on_success();
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            //TODO: Allow user to sign back (prevent wiping the state)
        });
    }
```

*dispatch* refers to the dispatch function provided by Redux

*current_func* refers to the action creator

*error* refers to the error returned by the API

*handling* refers to the error handling function for other types of errors

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you figure out?